# Cardinality and a set with non-numeric elements

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I was recently given this question by one of my professors:

Consider the set
$\Omega = \{ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\} \: |\:  \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\: such\: that\: f(n)=f(N)\: for\: n\geq N \}$.

Show that $f$ is countable.

I don't understand what is really being asked here. How can $f$ be countable or not? $f$ itself doesn't appear to be a set with elements to count. Any help with what the question is actually asking would be appreciated! I'm sure once I understand that I'd be able to make some progress.

Thanks!

Comment: You can think of these as the [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), with two representations for each.

Comment: This is the set of two-valued functions (the values being $0$ and $1$) that are eventually constant. Does this remind you of dyadic expansions of numbers between $0$ and $1$ whose expansions are eventually constant? Note that "eventually constant" dyadic expansions are all eventually periodic (in a very special way), which should tell you right away why (if not provide a formal proof) the set you're looking at is countable.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That's not really what the question is asking: the OP is confused by the sentence "Show that $f$ is countable," rather than "Show that $\Omega$ is countable."

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. The problem should be asking you to show that $\Omega$ is countable.

(Incidentally, since in set theory a function is a set of ordered pairs, we *can* talk about the cardinality of a function; but that's not what's going on here.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be $\Omega$ that is a set with elements.  If we didn't have the vertical bar and stuff after it, it would just be the set of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.  You could think of them as infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s.  You have probably seen the proof from Cantor that this set is uncountable.  With the restriction in each function there is some position in the sequence $N$ where the sequence becomes constant.  You are asked to determine whether this set is countable or not.